# How do I specify in a GET request that I can accept `application\pdf` responses?

Tags: http, pdf, get

A lot of websites in the Canadian government somehow check that you have Adobe Acrobat installed when you request a PDF from their server.

For example: https://cfr.forms.gov.ab.ca/form/cts1931.pdf

If you don't have it, ironically, they send you a PDF that tells you to download Adobe Acrobat.

I'm assuming their server checks some `accepted` request header and that's who it determines what to send.

My questions is, how can I fake a request to actually get the PDF contents in this case?

Comment: A web server cannot actually check if a particular application is installed.  All it can do is look at the client's `Accept` request header and send a response in a particular format that matches what the client is willing to accept.  Most web browsers will just omit `Accept`, or at least include `*/*` in it, to accept anything the server is willing to send, then the browser's local MIME settings are used to control which application to load based on what the server actually sends.

Comment: I have no trouble downloading that PDF using a non-browser HTTPS client of my own making.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Does the content say "Please wait..."?

Comment: nope, it is the full and final PDF

Comment: @RemyLebeau What program are you viewing resulting PDF with? Through curl, I get the "Please wait..." one.

Comment: I use Adobe Reader, but it has no influence on how the PDF file is downloaded. Like I said, I use a custom HTTP client of my own making for that, and it doesn't do anything special with the HTTP protocol. So the "Please wait" message has to be related to how the PDF is viewed, not how it is downloaded. I'll try tomorrow to view the PDF in some other non-Adobe viewers that I have.

Comment: I believe there's some sort of AJAX-y thing going on in the PDF or at least a hide/show because using Preview on Mac OS, I only ever see "Please wait...".

Comment: It is definitely the PDF itself.  When I download the PDF file via HTTP and open it in Adobe Reader, it displays the Affidavit form, as expected. When I open the *same* PDF file on the *same* PC using PDF Architect, I get the "Please Wait" message instead.  So this is not an HTTP issue, it is a PDF issue.

Comment: Ok, good to know! Thanks @RemyLebeau.